# Double-sided action figure, early 80s?

Tags: object-identification, toys

Around 1983 or '84, I had an odd action figure. From the waist down it was basically a guy in an orange spacesuit. From the waist up, the figure was double-sided. One side was again the dude in the orange jumpsuit. I think he had brown hair. He had a little button near his waist, and if you clicked it he would spin to the back. The backside also I think had brown hair, but now the guy was shirtless with blue skin and I think prominent veins. I guess this side looked somewhat like Mystique in the X-Men films. What was that? I don't think I had any of the other figures in the series, but I believe exactly one other figure had the odd-double sided mechanic. I don't remember ever watching a related show or cartoon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That would be the [Power Lords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Lords) series of toys by Revell. There was a comic run, even a video game, but never any cartoon associated with them. The particular character you describe is the main one, [Adam Power](http://www.action-figures.ca/power_lords.htm).

[image]

The main female character Shaya is somewhat disturbing, as her alternate form looks like something that escaped from a horror movie.

[image]

Comment: How exactly does this spinning button thing work?

Comment: @Stormblessed, as I recall, it was spring loaded. You had to manually turn them back to reset the button.

Comment: Pretty lame transformation mechanism. Even if you only look at it from the front, you can see the back pair of feet. This was better: https://he-man.fandom.com/wiki/King_Hiss